# How to put an icon on desktop for my java application that runs on Command Prompt

Tags: java, windows

so i'm trying to build a java application. However I only know how to implement a java application that runs on Command Prompt. I need help in building a java application that sets an icon on desktop and can be accessed from desktop through that icon. Application includes JFrame with menu bars, and an MS-Access database that is connected to it. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Try to create an executable jar file with your deliverables so that you can place it in desktop.

Comment: Great! Thank you. So i'll be searching for a tutorial website that will teach me how to do that. Any website recommended??

Comment: If you are going for an IDE there is an option to export it as jar file. If you are going for command line you can find lot of links. e.g http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Comment: Will do. Much appreciated.

Comment: So i read some material about creating JAR. It is clear to me how to create it. However what is still unclear to me is if the JAR runs on a browser and not on desktop? I don't want my app to run on a browser. i just need a way to access my app through a desktop icon and not javac file.java then java file through cmd

Comment: The first tutorial you should read is [the official one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/).

Answer (score 0):

Build the **.jar** file from your application and copy it to your Desktop